# Problems with retrieving database info through AJAX/jQuery using dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating dynamic input textbox fields through jQuery. When a user clicks the link, two input fields are created. On the left input, the user can type in a code (or DB table id) and on the right input, they should see the name related to the id as the result.

To accomplish this, I attached a `'blur'` event that will make an AJAX request to a PHP script which will query the database to retrieve the information. However my code is not working.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**consulta.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

            var contenedor      = $("#contenedor");
            var AddButton       = $("#agregarCampo");

            var x = $("#contenedor div").length + 1;
            var FieldCount = x-1;

            $(AddButton).click(function (e)
            {
                if(x)
                {
                  FieldCount++;
                  $(contenedor).append('<div class="added"><input type="text"  name="codigo[]" id="campo'+FieldCount+'" placeholder="Ingrese codigo ID '+ FieldCount +'"/><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre'+FieldCount+'" value=""></div>');
                  x++;
                }
            return false;
            });

          });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cliente">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Codigo
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="contenedor">
              <div class="added">
                <input type="text" name="codigo[]" id="codigo" placeholder="Ingrese codigo ID" required/>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
      <p>
      <a id="agregarCampo" href="#">Agregar Campo</a>
      </p>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cliente.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**cliente.js**

```
$(function(){
   $('#cliente').on('blur','#codigo',function(){
    var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
      var valor = this.value;
      if(valor.length>=1){
         var consulta = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'cliente.php',
            data:{codigo:valor},
            dataType:'JSON'
         });

         consulta.done(function(data){
            if(data.error!==undefined){
               $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: '+data.error);
               return false;
            } else {
               if(data.nombre!==undefined){$("#cliente #nombre").val(data.nombre);}
               return true;
            }
         });

      }
   });
});
```

**cliente.php**

```
<?php

$codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gabu");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conexion)) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$registros=mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from estudiantes where estudiante_id='$codigo'") or
  die("Problemas en el select:".mysqli_error());

if ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{
  $return = array('nombre' => $reg['nombre_estudiante']);
} else {
  $return = array('nombre'=>'No existe el registro');
}
   die(json_encode($return));
?>
```

This is how it should look like. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking please update your question to be more concise with the exact problem and what you would like the script to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems. The ones that stand out the most are the HTML IDs and Classes. Theres no reason to create IDs dynamically as you can use classes for reference. Also, in PHP, you should use the right syntax for `mysqli` and return a proper JSON, with headers.

This is what I would do:

**HTML/JS:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var $contenedor = $("#contenedor");
                var $AddButton = $("#agregarCampo");

                $AddButton.click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var FieldCount = $contenedor.children('div').length + 1;
                    $contenedor.append('<div class="added">\
                                            <input type="text" class="codigo_input" placeholder="Ingrese codigo ID ' + FieldCount + '"/>\
                                            <input type="text" class="nombre_input" >\
                                          </div>');
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cliente">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Codigo
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="contenedor">
                            <div class="added">
                                <input type="text" class="codigo_input" placeholder="Ingrese codigo ID" required/>
                                <input type="text" class="nombre_input" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <a id="agregarCampo" href="#">Agregar Campo</a>
                        </p>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#cliente').on('blur', '.codigo_input', function () {
                    var $container = $(this).closest(".added");
                    var valor = $(this).val();

                    if (valor.length >= 1) {

                        var consulta = $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'cliente.php',
                            data: {codigo: valor},
                            dataType: 'JSON'
                        });

                        consulta.done(function (data) {
                            if (data.error !== undefined) {
                                $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: ' + data.error);
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                if (data.nombre !== undefined) {
                                    $container.find('.nombre_input').val(data.nombre);
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        });

                        consulta.error(function(a,b,c){
                            console.log(a);
                            console.log(b);
                            console.log(c);
                        });

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gabu");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$registros = mysqli_query($conexion, "select * from estudiantes where estudiante_id='$codigo'") or
die("Problemas en el select:" . mysqli_error($conexion));

if (mysqli_num_rows($registros) > 0) {
    $reg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($registros);
    $return = array('nombre' => $reg['nombre_estudiante']);
} else {
    $return = array('nombre' => 'No existe el registro');
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, this was what I needed... Thank you very much, now I understand the because I did not, and now I understand jSON, in truth, thank you. @CodeGodie

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to debug the frontend and backend separately.

I've rewritten the clinte.php to only display json

```
<?php

$codigo=$_POST['codigo'];

$return = $_POST;
$return = array('nombre' => 1337);

die(json_encode($return));
?>
```

and it seems it's working.

The question is if you're selecting by the ID column, should it be number?

Can you add your db structure as well?

Comment: It was try to place a code and bringing the name I had that code, if it does not show that there is the code, they already solved it, but you're right, will improve the mysqli thank you for your time. @Richard